# Fast way to update file names in Mac OS X

Tags: mac, finder, macros

I have about 200 images that I optimized with PunyPNG, but it appended .png to the end so all of the images are .gif.png.  I don't want to have to manually edit the file name of each one to just be .gif, so what would be the easiest way to automatically remove the .png from the end of all of the file names in the folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please make sure that these are actually .gif files and not .png files. (It seems more likely that they are misnamed .png's rather than misnamed .gif's, but if you're *sure*...)

Open the terminal.

Type in:

`cd "/folder/in/question"` (replace with actual folder name)

Press enter. Type in:

`for file in *.gif.png ; do mv "$file" "${file%.png}" ; done`

Comment: If you want to keep the "png" and remove the "gif" you may be able to use `mv "$file" "${file/.gif}"`

Comment: @Dennis: It's all fun and games until you get to `Christmas.gift.gif.png`... If you want to keep the `.png`, use `mv "$file" "${file%.gif.png}.png"`.

Comment: @Gilles: or `${file/.gif./.}`

Comment: @Dennis: `dodelijke.gif.fles.gif.png` still kills you...

Comment: @Gilles: You've checkmated me (but there's always `${file/%.gif.png/.png}` as my consolation prize). It's no consolation that it's two characters longer than yours. :(